# ¿Como testear a conciencia una app en Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, test

Estoy aprendiendo acerca del desarrollo de apps en Android Studio y tengo algunas aplicaciones subidas a Google Play, donde presentan algunos bloqueos en algunos dispositivos.

Por ejemplo soy consciente de que en los Samsung Galaxy S6 y S6 Edge me salta este error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: 
>     at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw (DisplayListCanvas.java:260)
>     at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap (Canvas.java:1420)
>     at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw (BitmapDrawable.java:545)

El problema es que no sé en que momento exacto salta este error, y no puedo arreglarlo, por lo que me gustaría poder testear yo mismo con el dispositivo que presenta errores y con un debugger estos fallos, ya que en los emuladores que tengo configurados no me ocurren.

Alguna solución?

Comment: ¿Tienes acceso a la consola de desarrollo Google Play?Si el LogCat menciona "Canvas: trying to draw too large" agregalo a tu pregunta,  ¿Que realiza tu aplicación?  para que los usuarios de la comunidad den mejores respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atrapar esa clase de errores puede ser complicado, yo suelo hacer unitTest a la logica y servicios que consume la app, ademas le agrego crashlytics de firebase que ayuda bastante porque te da bastantes datos para poder atrapar el error. Finalmente cuando tengo este tipo de problemas en prod, busco en el codigo que lo podria estar causando e investigo.

---

Este error que vos planteas mas especificamente puede deberse a que alguna imagen se esta intentando resizear a un tamaño muy grande y por cuestiones de memoria explota.

Si tenes alguna imagen muy grande por ejemplo un splash de pantalla completa asegurate de que exista la carpeta `res/xhdpi` y `res/xxhdpi` que contengan una version ya ajustada a cada tamaño. Asi no la tiene re resizear en memoria si se da el caso.

Finalmente busca un dispositivo similar y testealo bien.

Comment: La aplicación obtiene imagenes (gifs) alojados en un servidor y los muestra usando Volley por lo que no son recursos de la app. Si es cierto que la pantalla de inicio es una imagen de 1080x1920 alojada en la carpeta Drawable, crees que ese podría ser el problema?

Comment: El Galaxy S6 tiene una alta densidad y usa los recursos de xxxhdpi por lo que si tenes una imagen tan grande en el drawable y no especificas ninguna densidad Android va a resizear esa imagen para que se ajuste a la densidad de la pantalla y como la pantalla es muy grande va a intentar crear un archivo en memoria enorme, pon el splash en la carpeta res/drawable-xxhdpi. Ademas segurate de que ninguna imagen te pese mas de 1mb eso tambien puede traer complicaciones por el mismo motivo.